# Datatable column headers missing when vertical scroll is enabled

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, datatables

Below is my datatable initialization

```
$('table.datatable').DataTable({
    scrollY:        "150px",
    scrollCollapse: true,
    fixedHeader: true,
    bFilter : false,
    paging:         false,
    bLengthChange : false,
    pageLength : 5,
    "language" : {
       "zeroRecords" : "No Requests found"
    }
});
```

I want to have vertical scroll and no pagination. When i include 'scrollY' for vertical scroll i have the vertical scroll bars, but the column headers are disappearing. If anyone had a similar experience please help me with this.

Comment: Something else is interfering with your DataTable... with the setting you provided, it works as intended: http://live.datatables.net/bivozazi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Rushikumar Excellent dude, one of the css I included was the culprit. Appreciate your effort to debug it on http://live.datatables.net. Thank you very much :)